# ionic capacitor ios iframe cookie problem not set and load

Tags: ionic-framework, cookies, iframe, ionic4

I made an app that contains an iframe, there is an error message in the iframe that it can't use cookies.
I checked the storage for the cookie is empty.
I found a package but it doesn't solve the iframe problem.
it doesn't help: https://github.com/agarcia17/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine

Comment: Did you solved this problem?